# What does "(6)" in "curl: (6) Could not resolve host: xyz.net" refer to?

Tags: curl, command-line-interface

I am using curl to get data from an url. It returns "could not resolve host" which is fine an plausible since there is no nameserver and the /etc/hosts does not have an entry for that host.

I wonder if anabody can tell me what the six "(6)" in the cli output means?
It's not a manpage section...

Thanks for your answers

idiv